# What does "file.sync = true" do?

Tags: ruby, file

I had a look at the docs but I can't seem to find the relevant part. Can anyone tell me what the call to `sync` is for in the following code?

```
fh = Tempfile.new('tmp')
fh.sync = true
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sets the sync mode of the file.

This affects future operations and causes output to be written without block buffering.

If `f.tty?` is true, that is, if the file is connected to a console-like device, then output is not block buffered. But when output goes to a pipe or file, `f.tty?` will be false and the I/O library will switch to *block buffering,* that is, accumulating output in a buffer and writing it only if the file is closed, the program exits, or the buffer fills up. This is faster and the end result is the same.

Setting `f.sync = true` defeats this switch. This can be useful if the output of the pipe is connected to something that actually is a console or in some way interactive or if the contents of the file are being actively monitored.

Comment: +1, it's important to maintain the buffering as much as possible. Nothing like discovering how useful buffering is the hard way.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, it writes any data buffered in memory out to disk right away.

Comment: Sounds correct.  I wonder why it's not in the docs.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html

Comment: "I wonder why it's not in the docs."? Because it's part of IO? Try `ri IO.sync`.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading. The operation that writes the data out immediately is `fh.fsync`. The `#sync` method sets the sync mode and affects future operations.  Now, if you meant "causes *future* operations to write data right away", then, sure.

Answer (score 2):

Tempfile inherits from IO. From the [`IO.sync`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-sync) docs:

```
  ios.sync    -> true or false

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns the current ``sync mode'' of ios. When sync mode is true, all
output is immediately flushed to the underlying operating system and is not
buffered by Ruby internally. See also IO#fsync.

  f = File.new("testfile")
  f.sync   #=> false
```