# Ruby program not running properly in terminal

Tags: ruby, windows, command-line, terminal, git-bash

I am writing very basic Ruby programs to learn variables and methods for class. I wrote the following:

```
puts 'What is your favorite number?'
fav_num = gets.chomp.to_i
better_num = fav_num + 1
puts better_num.to_s + ' ' + 'is a much better number than ' + fav_num.to_s + '!'
```

When I run this program in my terminal using `ruby variables-methods.rb`, it goes to the next line and does nothing. If I type in a number, this happens:

```
22
What is your favorite number?
23 is a much better number than 22!
```

I updated Ruby in my terminal.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: Git Bash. I am on a Windows machine.

Comment: bash is your shell, what's your terminal? Is it whatever you get with "command prompt"?

Comment: I can use Windows Powershell or the command prompt...does that help?

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem of flushing in-/out-streams. I have no clue how it is done in your terminal, but the code below should do the trick (note the explicit `flush` of output stream):

```
$stdout.puts 'What is your favorite number?'
$stdout.flush
fav_num = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_i
better_num = fav_num + 1
$stdout.puts better_num.to_s + ' is a much better number than ' + fav_num.to_s + '!'
```

Comment: That did the trick! Will I have to do this for all future code?

Comment: It seems that if I run my original program from either PowerShell or the command line, it works.

Comment: In general, you should not need to `flush` streams. But windows is famous for having weird terminal emulators, so I can not assure you will never meet this superfluous `flush` in the future :)

Comment: The STDOUT stream should always flush anytime a line-end character is seen, which will happen when `puts` processes the expression. That can be tested by simply turning on `sync` for the stream: `STDOUT.sync = true`, then running the code without using `flush`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8949007/128421.