# Does ruby IO.gets read from a buffer?

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain to me how `pipe.gets` works in this instance? is IO object (pipe in this example), buffering the output? How is it that I can take my time to read the output from stdout using "gets"? I even put a sleep in there before reading through `gets` to make sure I'm not crazy.

```
def run_script(commands)
      raw_output = nil
      IO.popen("./db", "r+") do |pipe|
        commands.each do |command|
          pipe.puts command
        end

        pipe.close_write

        # Read entire output
        raw_output = pipe.gets(nil)
      end
      raw_output.split("\n")
    end
```

Comment: fyi `IO#popen` will return the last statement inside the block, so you could do `raw_output = IO.popen(...) do` or even leave out the entire `raw_output` variable and simply end the block with `pipe.gets(nil).split("\n")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pipe.sync` options defaults to `false` for `popen`. Meaning that the commands are buffered by Ruby until you call `pipe.close_write`, `pipe.close`, exit the program or the buffer is full. The buffer is then flushed, providing all buffered data written to the other program.

For more info check out the [`IO#sync`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-sync) documentation and/or [What does “file.sync = true” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948933/what-does-file-sync-true-do)

Based on your comment I'm not sure I understand the question. The only reason I can think of why `pipe.gets(nil)` would return `nil` is if the other program has no output.

The other option is that `pipe.gets(nil)` will block. This could happen if `pipe` is never flushed, meaning the other program is still waiting for the input. Because the other program now blocks and hasn't closed their standard output `pipe.gets(nil)` will also block. `pipe.gets(nil)` will read everything from the standard input. How does it know everything is read? It knows because a closed connection means there can't be send any data, thus it waits for a closed connection.

```
Ruby                stdout -------> stdin    ./db
                    stdin <-------- stdout

                                             (blocked because empty)
pipe.puts("a")      "a\n"  -------> empty    <read from stdin>
                    empty <-------- empty

                                             (still blocked)
pipe.puts("b")      "a\nb\n" -----> empty    <read from stdin>
                    empty <-------- empty

(flushing stdout)                            (continues consuming "a\nb\n")
pipe.close_write    empty ----/---> "a\n\b"  <read from stdin>
                    empty <-------- empty

(blocks because empty)
pipe.gets(nil)      empty ----/---> empty    <send data to stdout>
                    empty <-------- "data\n"

(continues consuming "data\n")               (flushing stdout)
pipe.gets(nil)      empty ----/---> empty    <close stdout>
                    "data\n" <--/-- empty
```

I hope the above helps demonstrate the process of your current code.

Comment: hmm. I'm still confused. I played around and removed `close_write` and nothing happened. it still behaved the same way. I'm just confused why `pipe.gets` returns anything at all. By the time I call it I thought I would have "missed" the output. I'm guessing pipe.gets reads from a buffer....

Comment: @user1099123 I've updated the answer, hoping to clarify the behaviour of your current code.

Comment: thanks man really appreciate it. the drawing helps. `pipe.gets(nil)` didn't return nil for me. in fact it returns data. I was under the impression that once data entered stdout of the calling program that the callee wouldn't get it in time before calling `pipe.gets`. I guess from your drawing it sits there until someone consumes it.